# Download PDF - Failed: Network error, PHP-FPM and Nginx

Tags: php, pdf, nginx, download

I have a very simple script for downloading a pdf:

```
$path = __DIR__.'/sample_file.pdf';
$pathinfo = pathinfo($path);
$fsize = filesize($path);
$filename = $pathinfo['basename'];

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Pragma:public");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=" . $filename);
header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
@readfile($path);
exit;
```

This works fine for files smaller than `10mb`. But anything over that I get an error and the download fails. Have tried in a number of browsers and get similar results. In all cases the download fails.

Chrome: `Failed: Network error`

Firefox: `[filename].pdf.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.`

Opera: `Interrupted: Network error`

IE (10): `[filename].pdf couldn't be downloaded.`

I know the filepaths are correct, or else it wouldn't work with files smaller than 5mb.

Reading the php docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) on `readfile` some have suggested disabling `output_buffering` (currently set to `4096` in php.ini) before calling `readfile`. I have yet to try this but I'm not convinced it is the solution.

`zlib.output_compression` is disabled. I am not seeing any errors in my logs. I am also not seeing any errors in the network pane in Chrome inspector.

I have tried downloading with chunks but get the same result. I have researched similar answers but all seem to be browser specific, i.e. working in some browsers but not others.

Comment: How long does the download take?

Comment: @bassxzero it fails within a couple of seconds. Doesn't even really get started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use pausing or something like this and you target file is locking. 
 It is possible that your security software is scanning and locking the file, which may still be in the system temporary folder after you pause the download.